# Pushing a new viewcontroller from a tableview in a tab bar app

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I've got an app with a `UITabBarController` that controls several `UIViewControllers`. Within that controller there is a `UITableViewController`. I'm trying to figure out how I can select a row on my tableview and push the view controller of one of my other tabs while actually navigating to that tab.

I've used `performSegueWithIdentifier`: but it pushes the new view onto the same tab that my tableview is in. I'd like to navigate to the tab that the view I'm pushing to is on.

In case I haven't been clear: My tableview is in Tab 1. I click on a row. I want to get to Tab 2. So far I've been able to push the view controller for Tab 2 onto Tab 1. No Good.

Can anyone shed some light?

Thanks

Comment: Share some code. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSUInteger theIndex;
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:theIndex];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    UIViewController *tab2ViewController = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];

    NewViewControllerToPush *mvc = [[NewViewControllerToPush alloc] init];
    [tab2ViewController.navigationController pushViewController:mvc animated:YES];
    [mvc release];
}
```

When you enter the viewControllers in your tabBar, make sure to wrap them inside a UINavigationControllers, otherwise you would not be able to use push and pop functionalities.

Comment: thanks for the help. until this point i was ignorant of NewViewControllerToPush. it may come in handy in the future.

Comment: NewViewControllerToPush is just a name I came up with, You should replace it with the name of any ViewController you are pushing into the navigation controller

Comment: haha you can tell i've been staring at this screen for too long. thanks anyway @aryaxt.